# Can an Android Xamarin.Forms App Access Windows File System

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm developing an Android Xamarin.forms application to run on a S8 Phone. Upon connecting the phone to the Windows machine via a USB cable connection, can the program read from or write to the Windows 10 file system?

Comment: Well i don't think this is possible right now in ios, android or uwp

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you don't. With a mobile Xamarin.Forms application you can access the Device FileSystem, either Internal or External Storage. However you are talking about external storage of a different device, and Xamarin does not support that functionality.

[Xamarin Docs on Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=macos)